# getPageNumber Open Office

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-writer

I have the below code which returns the total number of pages in my document. I can call this with javascript soapplet.getNumberOfPages()

I want to do a similar method that will return just the PageNumber. I have found this class com.sun.star.text.TextField.PageNumber but I cannot figure out how to return a string of the PageNumber. In javascript then I will be able to search the document for a certain string and depending where the string is found I will be able to determine the page number on that document where string exists. I can then tell the printer to print this page from the headed paper tray. I've googled for a day or two and can't find anything. Thanks

```
public int getNumberOfPages()
{
    XController xController = OODocument.getCurrentDocument().getXFrame().getController();

    XTextViewCursorSupplier supTextViewCursor =
                (XTextViewCursorSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XTextViewCursorSupplier.class, xController);

    XTextViewCursor curTextView = supTextViewCursor.getViewCursor();
    XPageCursor curPage =
                (XPageCursor) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XPageCursor.class, curTextView);
    curPage.jumpToLastPage();
    System.out.println("pages = " + curPage.getPage());
    return curPage.getPage();
}
```

I'm rethinking this now and wondering if its possible in javascript to find the string and then to return the page number that string is on. code I have is:

```
if(printOnPlainPaper == true)    {

            if(soApplet.isConnected())  
            {
                soDoc = soDoc + soApplet.getEncodedHtmlDocument( null );
                if(soDoc.indexOf("zzzzz"))  
                {                                       
                    alert("trueeeee");
                }
                else 
                {
                    soApplet.printDocument(PLAIN_PAPER, "1-");    // print page 1 to plain paper printer
                }
            }
        //soApplet.printDocument(PLAIN_PAPER, "1-");    // print page 1 to plain paper printer
    }
```

It can find the string but then how do I get it to tell me the page number its on?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone needs it I worked it out. Code below searches document , finds string and returns page number its on

```
public int searchPageNumber()
{
    XController xController = OODocument.getCurrentDocument().getXFrame().getController();

    XTextViewCursorSupplier supTextViewCursor =
                (XTextViewCursorSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XTextViewCursorSupplier.class, xController);

    XTextViewCursor curTextView = supTextViewCursor.getViewCursor();

    // gets the page cursor and assigns the text view cursor to the page
    XPageCursor curPage =
                (XPageCursor) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                    XPageCursor.class, curTextView);
    System.out.println("The current page number is " + curPage.getPage());

    // gets the model
    XModel model = xController.getModel();
    // assigns model to the document
    XTextDocument xTextDocument = (XTextDocument) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XTextDocument.class, model);
    // Xsearchable so we can search the text
    XSearchable xSearchable = (XSearchable) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XSearchable.class, xTextDocument); 
    XSearchDescriptor xsd = (XSearchDescriptor) xSearchable.createSearchDescriptor(); 

    xsd.setSearchString("zzzzz");

    XInterface xfi = (XInterface) xSearchable.findFirst(xsd); 
    if (xfi != null) { 
        XTextRange xStart = (com.sun.star.text.XTextRange) UnoRuntime.queryInterface( 
                com.sun.star.text.XTextRange.class, xfi); 

        curTextView.gotoRange(xStart, false); 
    } 

    System.out.println("current page = " + curPage.getPage());
    return curPage.getPage();
}
```